# Adding Minecraft to Steam's games library with multiple JREs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, steam

Is there any trick to getting Minecraft to launch from the Steam games library?

When I add Minecraft as a non-Steam game via the usual process, I see it is added to the library. However when I try to launch it, nothing happens after Steam's 'Launching game' progress bar/dialog box.

I am running it on a 64bit JRE however my searching here suggests that this shouldn't be an issue in itself;
[Adding Minecraft to Steam with 64bit JRE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65377/adding-minecraft-to-steam-with-64bit-jre)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add Minecraft to Steam?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49284/how-do-i-add-minecraft-to-steam)

Comment: Thanks but it's not - I've added it, it just doesn't run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a follow up; I've since bought enough PC components to warrant a re-install. I had no trouble adding Minecraft via the standard 'non-Steam game' function this time.

I suspect it was to do with having both x32 & x64 Java versions on the previous install whereas this time I've only got x64 installed (so far).

No sensible details on how to deal with the issue for those searching, unfortunately - but hey, my problem is fixed!

Answer (score 4):

You may need to go to http://minecraft.net and download the .exe instead of the .jar (or whatever format it is in) due to the way Steam expects games to be launched.

Comment: Ta for the answer. The launcher (minecraft.exe) was running but seemed to close straight away. Possibly an issue with the CLASSPATH variable & multiple Java installs.

Answer (score 1):

Find a working shortcut to the game somewhere on your pc or create one. Right click the shortcut > properties and copy the data from the "target" section. in your steam library right click the minecraft launcher and hit properties in the target section paste the data for the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing 32 bit java, then 64 bit java and then launch it using "[64-bit java location]\java.exe" -jar "[Minecraft.exe location]" and remember to put the location to Minecraft.exe in the start-in box

Answer (score -5):

Since it's not available normally, go to + on your library and click on "add non-steam game". Browse for your Minecraft then click ok. TA DA!!!

Comment: Hi @Tyler. It's customary to read more than just the question title before posting an answer around here.